# Modifying response file in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this JS code:

```
$.post("[MyRouteName]", data, callback);
```

And I have route in my ASP .NET app:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "MyRouteName",
                "myrouteurl",
                new { controller = "Foo", action = "Bar", id = "" }
            );
```

I remember that I can force ASP .NET MVC to replace `[MyRouteName]` with `myrouteurl` when file that contains JS is requested, but I can not remember exactly which component I need to override.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Sorry but you're wrong. You have to provide "myrouteurl", not the routename in the javascript file.

Comment: @RobertoConteRosito I implemented this, check the answer if you are interested how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this result. To implement this I wrote my own HttpHandler:

```
public class JsRoutingHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public JsRoutingHttpHandler()
    {

    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var phisicalPath = context.Server.MapPath(context.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath);
        var file = File.ReadAllLines(phisicalPath);
        var routeCatchRegex = new Regex(@"\[Route:([a-zA-Z]+)\]");
        for (int index = 0; index < file.Length; index++)
        {
            var line = file[index];
            var matches = routeCatchRegex.Matches(line);
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                var routeName = match.Groups[1];
                var url = "ERROR[NO ROUTE FOUND]";
                if (Resolver.RouteUrl.ContainsKey(routeName.Value))
                {
                    url = Resolver.RouteUrl[routeName.Value];
                }
                line = line.Replace(match.Value, url);
            }
            context.Response.Output.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I registered it in Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*.js" resourceType="File" name="JsRoutingHandler" type="AAYW.Core.Web.HttpHandler.JsRoutingHttpHandler"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

And then I tested it and achieved effect that I wanted:
File that I have:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var a = "[Route:SaveEntity]";
});
```

And File that I got:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var a = "admin/entity/save";
});
```

Hope this can help someone!